# trying install octobercms and running the install.php file in the browser using homestead and keep getting 'no input specified'

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, octobercms

I am very new to php, laravel and octobercms and am trying to install it. I have laravel installed and now I am trying to do the wizard installation for octobercms and currently when I try to run install.php in the browser it gives me 'no input specified'.

this is my Homestead.yaml file:

```
box: laravel/homestead-7
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Homestead/Projects
      to:   /Users/marika/Homestead/Projects  

sites:
    - map: local.octobercms.com
      to:  /Users/marika/Homestead/Projects/DevelopmentalDesigners

databases:
    - homestead
```

this is what I have in my hosts file:

```
192.168.10.10  local.octobercms.com
```

as for my folders file in my and sites paths I did a pwd in terminal so I know they are the right paths as shown below:

```
➜  Projects git:(master) ✗ pwd
/Users/marika/Homestead/Projects
➜  Projects git:(master) ✗ cd DevelopmentalDesigners 
➜  DevelopmentalDesigners git:(master) ✗ pwd
/Users/marika/Homestead/Projects/DevelopmentalDesigners
➜  DevelopmentalDesigners git:(master) ✗
```

my files look like this:

[This is the image of my files in my text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGxed.png)

and my install.php file looks like this:

```
<?php include 'install_files/php/boot.php'; ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>October Installation</title>

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="install_files/css/vendor.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="install_files/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="install_files/css/controls.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="install_files/css/animations.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="install_files/css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Base URL -->
        <?php if (!isset($fatalError)): ?>
            <script>
            <!--
                installerBaseUrl = '<?= $installer->getBaseUrl() ?>';
            // -->
            </script>
        <?php endif ?>
    </head>
    <body class="js">

        <div id="wrap">

            <!-- Header -->
            <header>
                <div class="container" id="containerHeader"></div>

                <!-- Title -->
                <section class="title">
                    <div class="container" id="containerTitle"></div>
                </section>

            </header>

            <!-- Body -->
            <section class="body">
                <?php if (isset($fatalError)): ?>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="callout callout-danger"><?= $fatalError ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="container" id="containerBody"></div>
                <?php endif ?>
            </section>

        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="container" id="containerFooter"></div>
        </footer>

        <?php if (!isset($fatalError)): ?>

            <!-- Render Partials -->
            <?php
                $partialList = array(
                    'header',
                    'title',
                    'footer',
                    'check',
                    'check/fail',
                    'config',
                    'config/mysql',
                    'config/pgsql',
                    'config/sqlite',
                    'config/sqlsrv',
                    'config/fail',
                    'config/database',
                    'config/admin',
                    'config/advanced',
                    'starter',
                    'themes',
                    'themes/theme',
                    'project',
                    'project/project',
                    'project/plugins',
                    'project/plugin',
                    'project/themes',
                    'project/theme',
                    'project/suggestion',
                    'project/fail',
                    'progress',
                    'progress/fail',
                    'complete',
                );
            ?>

            <?php foreach ($partialList as $file): ?>
                <script type="text/template" data-partial="<?= $file ?>">
                    <?php include 'install_files/partials/'.$file.'.htm'; ?>
                </script>
            <?php endforeach ?>

            <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="install_files/js/vendor.js"></script>
            <script src="install_files/js/app.js"></script>
            <script src="install_files/js/check.js"></script>
            <script src="install_files/js/config.js"></script>
            <script src="install_files/js/starter.js"></script>
            <script src="install_files/js/themes.js"></script>
            <script src="install_files/js/project.js"></script>
            <script src="install_files/js/progress.js"></script>
            <script src="install_files/js/complete.js"></script>

            <!-- Bespoke Properties -->
            <script>
                /*
                 * Checker Page
                 */
                Installer.Pages.systemCheck.title = 'System Check'
                Installer.Pages.systemCheck.nextButton = 'Agree & Continue'

                Installer.Pages.systemCheck.requirements = [
                    { code: 'phpVersion', label: 'PHP version 5.4 or greater required' },
                    { code: 'curlLibrary', label: 'cURL PHP Extension is required' },
                    { code: 'liveConnection', label: 'Test connection to the installation server' },
                    { code: 'writePermission', label: 'Permission to write to directories and files', reason: 'The installer was unable to write to the installation directories and files.' },
                    { code: 'pdoLibrary', label: 'PDO PHP Extension is required' },
                    { code: 'mcryptLibrary', label: 'MCrypt PHP Extension is required' },
                    { code: 'mbstringLibrary', label: 'Mbstring PHP Extension is required' },
                    { code: 'sslLibrary', label: 'OpenSSL PHP Extension is required' },
                    { code: 'zipLibrary', label: 'ZipArchive PHP Library is required' },
                    { code: 'gdLibrary', label: 'GD PHP Library is required' }
                ]

                /*
                 * Config Page
                 */
                Installer.Pages.configForm.title = 'Configuration'
                Installer.Pages.configForm.nextButton = 'Continue'

                Installer.Pages.configForm.sections = [
                    { code: 'database', label: 'Database', category: 'General', handler: 'onValidateDatabase', partial: 'config/database' },
                    { code: 'admin', label: 'Administrator', category: 'General', handler: 'onValidateAdminAccount', partial: 'config/admin' },
                    { code: 'advanced', label: 'Advanced', category: 'Advanced', handler: 'onValidateAdvancedConfig', partial: 'config/advanced' }
                ]

                /*
                 * Starter Page
                 */
                Installer.Pages.starterForm.title = 'Getting started'

                /*
                 * Themes Page
                 */
                Installer.Pages.themesForm.title = 'Start from a theme'

                /*
                 * Project Page
                 */
                Installer.Pages.projectForm.title = 'Project details'
                Installer.Pages.projectForm.nextButton = 'Install!'

                Installer.Pages.projectForm.sections = [
                    { code: 'project', label: 'Project', partial: 'project/project' },
                    { code: 'plugins', label: 'Plugins', partial: 'project/plugins' },
                    { code: 'themes', label: 'Themes', partial: 'project/themes' }
                ]

                /*
                 * Progress Page
                 */
                Installer.Pages.installProgress.title = 'Installation progress...'
                Installer.Pages.installProgress.steps = [
                    { code: 'getMetaData', label: 'Requesting package information' },
                    { code: 'downloadCore', label: 'Downloading application files' },
                    { code: 'downloadPlugins', label: 'Downloading plugin: ' },
                    { code: 'downloadThemes', label: 'Downloading theme: ' },
                    { code: 'extractCore', label: 'Unpacking application files' },
                    { code: 'extractPlugins', label: 'Unpacking plugin: ' },
                    { code: 'extractThemes', label: 'Unpacking plugin: ' },
                    { code: 'setupConfig', label: 'Building configuration files' },
                    { code: 'createAdmin', label: 'Create admin account' },
                    { code: 'setupProject', label: 'Setting website project' },
                    { code: 'finishInstall', label: 'Finishing installation' }
                ]

                /*
                 * Final Pages
                 */
                Installer.Pages.installComplete.title = 'Congratulations!'

            </script>

        <?php endif ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

any help would be appreciated! I am really lost! I have been trying to figure this out for days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the official docs and have no issues with installation on my Homestead. I hope it will help you.

http://octobercms.com/docs/console/commands#console-install

Comment: the console install gives me an error stating:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.

I seem to be the only person having this error installing october. I don't know what's wrong!

and when I try the wizard installation I get 'no input specified' when I try and run it in my browser

Comment: Something is off here. When you use CLI installation procedure the laravel framework of OctoberCMS version should be 5.0.33 and your version is 5.0.9. It's like you are installing from the different repo.

Comment: I'm finding the OctoberCMS documentation to be pretty thin and not enough to cover the wide range of circumstances. Having the same issue and docs don't help.